# JScrollPane add to frame issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I currently have multiple jpanels on a jframe. I can add all of the jpanels fine to the jframe but when I try and add a jscrollpane, nothing shows up. Essentially I just want a jscrollbar/pane on the jframe so that I can scroll down as the size of the jpanels goes off screen. This is the main code that I used:

```
   JPanel Jpanel = new JPanel();
   JScrollPane Jpane = new JScrollPane();

   frame.getContentPane().add(Jpanel);
   frame.getContentPane().add(Jpane);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the JPanel to the scroll pane, then add the scrollpane to the frame.
One of the way of doing it is when creating the JScrollPane, with the constructor :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Comment: Did you add the scrollPane to the frame ? Could you show more code ?

Comment: Yeah essentially I just want to put the scrollPane to the frame, not the Jpanel. When I do this I get an error saying that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container"

Comment: Show us the whole class if you can.

Comment: i can't really as it's an assignment. I'm just having issues with that one particular part :(

Comment: If "frame" is a JFrame, you don't need the getContentPane(), you can (and should) do a "add()" directly.

Comment: Changed it to add. Still the same issue. Am I getting it wrong that I can add jpanels to a jframe and then add the scrollpane to the jframe? is there a different and better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you must not add the JPanels to the JFrame if you put them in a JScrollPane. You add things to the scrollPane, and then you add the scrollPane to the JFrame. Without more code, I can't really help you, sorry !

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have msn or skype perhaps where we could IM and I could send you more code?

Comment: Nope, I don't do that for assignment, sorry. mKorbel has posted a more comprehensive answer, I'm sure you can make something that work with his answer.

Comment: the last sentence is wrong: you never use any of the _add_ methods of the scrollPane

Answer (score 1):

1) code that you posted caused that (`JFrame` has implemented by default `BorderLayout`, and there only one `JComponent` can to fill concrete `area` or layst added `JComponent`), only `frame.getContentPane().add(Jpane);` is possible to dispay on the screen

2) you have to accept that you can put to the `JScrollPane` only one `JComponent`

3) `JScrollPane` works correctly if is there used proper `LayoutManager` (not `AbsoluteLayout`) and in the case that `Dimmension` of `JComponent` is wider that `JViewport` from `JScrollPane`

Comment: random bullets (LayoutManagers are important but not an issue here) and hardly understandable in its wording (even me can barely glint at what exactly you mean)...

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered with the correct way to do it. The only thing I can think of that you might have done wrong (since it's not working), is that you're adding the panels to the jframe.

When you put a panel inside a scrollpane, you need to add the scrollpane to the JFrame, and not add the panel to the JFrame:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
add(scrollPane); // or if you have a panel inside a panel, add the pane to that panel. ie west.add(scrollPane);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this:

```
   JPanel Jpanel = new JPanel(); 
   JScrollPane Jpane = new JScrollPane(Jpanel); 

   frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   frame.add(Jpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The reason your panels aren't showing is beacause your frame doesn't know where to put them. It needs a layoutmanager.

Here you can find some basic layoutmanagers:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: nice try - but wrong: the frame (or more correctly: it's contentPane) already _has_ a BorderLayout

Comment: Hmm I wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing that out!
Has his question been answered now??